# How can I search multiple words at once?

Tags: php, search

I'm trying to use this script for searching more then one words at a time from a database. Now the problem is that my script only search one word once. But i want to search more words at once like (quick home jquery) if the database contains those words, then it will show the result. How could I do this with this script can any body tell me? or how could i search any keyword ? please help me...

```
<?php


include_once ('database_connection.php');

if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){
    $keyword =  trim($_GET['keyword']) ;
$keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $keyword);



$query = "select topictitle,topicdescription from topics where topictitle like '%$keyword%' or topicdescription like '%$keyword%'";

//echo $query;
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
if($result){
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)!=0){
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
     echo '<p> <b>'.$row['topictitle'].'</b> '.$row['topicdescription'].'</p>'   ;
    }
    }else {
        echo 'No Results for :"'.$_GET['keyword'].'"';
    }

}
}else {
    echo 'Parameter Missing';
}




?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Explode the search term so you get an array with each word and construct the query like that? The question is a bit confusing, probably something like this might work for you:

```
if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){
    $keyword =  trim($_GET['keyword']);
    $keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $keyword);
    $search_terms = explode(" ",$keyword);
    $query = "select topictitle,topicdescription from topics where 1 ";
    foreach($search_terms as $searchterm){
        $query = $query."or topictitle like '%".$searchterm."%' or topicdescription like '%".$searchterm." ';
    }
    ...
```

Comment: thanks you for quick answer . thing i want is srarch 2 or 3 words at a time . example when i type (jquery comment apple) and press search it will find those three word from database . my current script only show fast word search resulr (jquery) . i have little knowledge about php and my sql. if it possible then please answer me and show me where to put code. i put your code in my script it showing error.

Comment: Note that the snippet provided is just an example and might not work if you just copy and paste it into your code, also I made a mistake. It shoudl be `$search_terms = explode(" ",$keyword);`

Comment: please my brother it is my humble request to you that **show me how to put those code in my above code page** . i m new in php know nathing . and im great full that you at list spend some time reading my question .

Comment: thing i realy want is what ever i type one word or more if it match with any description or title frome the table it will show and highlite . is it possible with this script